# syslog to logstash _grokparsefailure

Tags: filter, tags, logstash, elastic-stack, syslog

I have ELK version 5.4.
I get syslog from a lot of networking machines like cisco, Juniper, Fortigate, F5.

the logstash.conf looks like:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 514
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 514
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "%{syslog_hostname}" ]
        replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
      }
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "syslog_hostname", "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I getting a lot of _grokparsefailure.
Maybe someone have an example of logstash.conf that will grok all the machine's syslog without _grokparsefailure?

Here are some log samples:

```
2018-01-30T09:30:14.675+0200: %ADMIN-6-INFO: [local] recorded login for administrator: (user)
Jan 25 17:26:47.767: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet8/11, changed state to down
Jan 30 01:13:43 SERVER_NAME lldpd[70354]: task_process_events: no read/accept method for (null) socket 0 <39>
Feb 1 09:14:43 SERVER_NAME rshd[64810]: user@user2 as root: cmd='/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx'
```

Thanks
TA

Comment: With a given log message set I can help construct a parser. Or at least show the first steps so you can finish the job if it's too big. Without all of the log patterns or every kind of log example I can't help.

Comment: thanks,
Here are some log samples:
2018-01-30T09:30:14.675+0200: %ADMIN-6-INFO: [local] recorded login for administrator: (user)
Jan 25 17:26:47.767: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet8/11, changed state to down
Jan 30 01:13:43  SERVER_NAME lldpd[70354]: task_process_events: no read/accept method for (null) socket 0
<39>Feb  1 09:14:43 SERVER_NAME rshd[64810]: user@user2 as root: cmd='/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this site to test the paterns:

> http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

And this site to look for premade patterns:

> https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns

For the first message the is this pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}: %{SYSLOGPROG} \[%{WORD:level}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

For the third message you can use this(if you like it):

```
%{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME:time} %{NOTSPACE:serverName} %{NOTSPACE:task}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

And in logstash you can use these like this:

```
filter{
  grok{
    match=>{"message" => <pattern1>}
  }
  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags]{
    mutate{ remove_tag => [ "_grokparsefailure" ] }
    grok{
      match=>{"message" => <pattern2>}
    }
  }
  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags]{
    mutate{ remove_tag => [ "_grokparsefailure" ] }
    grok{
      match=>{"message" => <pattern3>}
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to write your patterns to match the logs and if one does not fit, you remove the _grokparsefailure tag and try another one. If it fots, it won't try the next. It's a bit tedious but I have no better solution. If you can tag the logs by their source you can make this process faster by writing if conditions for that.
I hope this helps or at least gives you some direction.

Comment: Thanks,
Helped alot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write the parse failures to a file so you can create new patterns based on failures.

```
output {
  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    file {
      path => "/tmp/var/log/parse_failures.log
    }
  }
}
```

Not all devices follow syslog RFCs, so it's almost impossible to have a list of all available patterns.